# How to detect GPS enabled and disabled in Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

as the `CrossConnectivity.Current.ConnectivityChanged` event fired when any connection changes:

```cs
CrossConnectivity.Current.ConnectivityChanged += async (sender, args) =>
{
    if (!args.IsConnected)
        DependencyService.Get<ISQLite>().ShowSnackBar("No Internet Connection");
};
```

so How to detect GPS On/Off when any changes found on `CrossGeolocator` plugin in Xamarin.Forms?

Comment: I would suggest you use the [GeolocatorPlugin.](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/GeolocatorPlugin)

Answer (score 0):

The best way to find out about how any open-source project works is through its source code :-) . See the [`IGeolocator` class source code](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/GeolocatorPlugin/blob/master/src/Geolocator.Plugin/Abstractions/IGeolocator.shared.cs) for the interface available to you.

In your case you will probably be most interested in the `PositionChanged` event, which occurs whenever the position changes. There are also properties like `IsListening`, `IsGeolocationAvailable` and `IsGeolocationEnabled` which help you find out exactly in which state the GPS on the device is.

If you want an event when the listening property changes, then that is not implemented currently. You can however create a wrapper class through which you will access the `CrossGeolocator` plugin and which will implement such event when `StartListeningAsync` or `StopListeningAsync` is called.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of things you can do. The CrossGeolocator plugin does not have a straight-forward event like the Connectivity plugin.

First, you can check the `IsGeolocationAvailable` and `IsSupported`. This will tell you if this plugin is supported on the platform you are running on and if the user has granted permission to your app to read the location information. You can do something like this:

```
public bool IsLocationAvailable()
{
    if(!CrossGeolocator.IsSupported)
        return false;

    return CrossGeolocator.Current.IsGeolocationAvailable;
}
```

From there, you can hook into the `event EventHandler<PositionErrorEventArgs> PositionError;` method to be notified if for whatever reason the position could not be determined (anymore).

All documentation can be found on the [GitHub](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/GeolocatorPlugin) page or [documentation](https://jamesmontemagno.github.io/GeolocatorPlugin/).

Comment: I already use this process,but using this process I need to check every second for the connectivity checking.

Comment: Since you want to be using the location, you probably have some code in place to do this already I guess? Also, this is an event, so you will be notified "automatically" whenever something goes wrong, just like with the CrossConnectivity plugin

Answer (score 0):

While one may create such an event artificially, there is no such event at the system level and I don't think anyone made a plugin with such event.

To make it clear, your connectivity may change while the app is working and it makes sense to create such an event so that the app may react on that. GPS cannot be changed while the app is working - the only thing you can do is to check whether it is turned on or off and it can't be done without leaving and entering the app and you can check it with the API `CrossGeolocator.Current.IsGeolocationAvailable`. You may argue that the app may loose the GPS signal, but operating systems don't work that way and you can only recall the last known location and the time it was received.